# Change height value from px to % in .dotdotdot script

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I change the height value from 100 pixels to a percentage value? Lets say 50%. I'm fairly new to javascript...

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".item-info-overlay p").dotdotdot({
        ellipsis:"...",
        wrap:"word",
        height: 100,
        after:"a.readmore",})
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It appears that `height` only accepts numbers. `dotdotdot` only accepts the option if  `typeof opts.height == 'number'`.

Comment: Thanks! I kind of figured it will only accept numbers but was wondering if there was any workaround to add percentages. `typeof opts.height == 'number'` was this found in the main j dotdotdot js document? will changing `'number'` to `'percentage'` work? Probably not but just asking

Comment: Yes, I found it in the [javascript document](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/js/jquery.dotdotdot-1.2.1.js). No,"percentage" is not a valid [operand type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof). You'll want to accept "String" types, but you'll still need to add functionality to parse and validate the string as well as to compare element heights with a percentage value. It might be simpler to calculate a pixel height based on your desired percentage and then pass that pixel height to dotdotdot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than modifying the `dotdotdot` code, it might be simpler to calculate a pixel value based on your percentage and pass that pixel value to `dotdotdot`.

For example:

```js
// define your desired percentage
var percentage = 50;


jQuery(function() {

  // calculate pixel height based on your percentage
  var dot_height = jQuery('div#container').height() * (percentage / 100);

  jQuery("div#text").dotdotdot({
    ellipsis: "...",
    height: dot_height,
    wrap: "word",
    after: "a.readmore",
    watch: "window"
  });

});
```

```css
div#container {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery.dotdotdot/1.7.2/jquery.dotdotdot.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div id="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Morbi commodo, ipsum sed pharetra gravida, orci magna rhoncus neque, id pulvinar odio lorem non turpis. Nullam sit amet enim. Suspendisse id velit vitae ligula volutpat condimentum. Aliquam erat
    volutpat. Sed quis velit. Nulla facilisi. Nulla libero. Vivamus pharetra posuere sapien. Nam consectetuer. Sed aliquam, nunc eget euismod ullamcorper, lectus nunc ullamcorper orci, fermentum bibendum enim nibh eget ipsum. Donec porttitor ligula eu
    dolor. Maecenas vitae nulla consequat libero cursus venenatis. Nam magna enim, accumsan eu, blandit sed, blandit a, eros. Quisque facilisis erat a dui. Nam malesuada ornare dolor.
    <a href="#" class="readmore">Read More</a>

  </div>
</div>
```

If you're building a responsive site or your container is fluid, you can apply this same logic inside of a [throttled resize handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/resize#setTimeout).